# Fatal error: Call to undefined function updateRows()

Tags: function, pdo, undefined

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function updateRows()

but I have defined `updateRows()`, so what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if ($this->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
        $appleIDS[$i] = array(
            $row->id,
            $row->pass,
            $row->en_b_y,
            $row->en_b_m,
            $row->en_b_d,
            $row->sqa1,
            $row->sqa2,
            $row->sqa3
        );
        $i++;
    }
    updateRows($this->pre_head, $head);
    killTheConnection();
    return $appleIDS;
}
killTheConnection();
return $check;
}



function updateRows($pre_head, $head) // here is my function
{
    $this->mysqli_connet();
    try {
        $sql  = "UPDATE appleid " . "SET taken = 'yes'" . "," . "taken_time=now()" . "WHERE num>=$pre_head AND num<=$head;";
        $stmt = $GLOBALS['$connection']->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo $stmt->rowCount();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    killTheConnection();
}
?>
```

Comment: doesn't php read from top to bottom?

Comment: if i not mistaken, return will stop the code of the page unless return in a functions